# A trigger that detects that an UPDATE wouldn't change a row

Tags: postgresql, sql-update, database-trigger

I wrote the following trigger:

```
CREATE FUNCTION trig_func() RETURNS trigger AS $$
  BEGIN
    IF NEW = OLD
    THEN -- update would do nothing, doing something...
    END IF;
    RETURN NEW;
  END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
CREATE TRIGGER trig BEFORE UPDATE ON some_table
  FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE trig_func();
```

It makes it clear what I'd like to achieve, but what is the proper thing to put in place of `NEW = OLD`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `is distinct from` operator can compare complete rows and will handle nulls correctly.

So you want

```
if new is not distinct from old then 
   ...
end if;
```